# Two gaussian mixture fitting alternative to normal distribution sum. Global optimization

Tags: gaussian-mixture-distribution

I have data which I want to fit with two Gaussians while keeping one mean global. I have already written program with Python using scipy, lmfit, numpy libraries. This is my already fitted data results (least square):

```
mean1   sd1     A1      mean2   sd2     A2      y0
12.24   10.20   27526   25.50   20.42   30642   499.93
21.43   10.20   27529   25.51   20.39   30616   500.32
25.51   20.40   30599   30.61   10.21   27552   500.16
39.80   10.20   27536   25.52   20.42   30636   499.85
25.51   20.41   30616   48.98   10.21   27559   499.94
```

My function for calculations:

$$ y_0 + \sqrt{2/\pi}A_1/w_1\exp(-2(x-xc1)^2/w_1^2) + \sqrt{2/\pi}A_2/w_2\exp(-2(x-xc2)^2/w_2^2) $$
    Sorry, I dont know how to change into normal math formula.

This was a test, so correct answer had to be:

```
    mean1   sd1 A1      mean2   sd2 A2      y0
1   12      10  27000   25      20  30000   500
2   21      10  27000   25      20  30000   500
3   30      10  27000   25      20  30000   500
4   39      10  27000   25      20  30000   500
5   48      10  27000   25      20  30000   500
```

As you can see, It fits correctly for independent fitting. the problem is that my written fitting program sometimes "swaps first gaussian and second gaussian parameters values" which means now if i try to set mean2 fixed for every dataset, it will go wrong, because 3rd and 5th data sets are swapped so mean2 wont be correct (for this example mean2 always has to be 25). This problem is even more harsh in real data.
Basically, as I understand, because my function is f = y + gauss1 + gauss2, and both Gausses are identical, it doesnt see any difference in fitting gauss1 or gauss2 and sometimes mix it up.

How do You deal with such problems?

Comment: I've added LATEX to format your equation. Please check that I haven't inadvertently introduced any errors.

Comment: How do you determine the identities of component 1 versus component 2?  I notice that you are close if you get the means switched - that happens a lot in GMM's.  Often folks will sort by the mean of the component so component #1 is the largest mean, #2 is second largest etc...  BTW - your standard deviations for component #1 nearly all end with "0" - that is unlikely.  How are you picking the members of the distributions?  EM is the textbook fitting for GMM's - why are you using least-squares?  EM is robust.  LSQ should be initial condition for EM fit.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to understand the issue of *identifiability*. The order of individual Gaussian distribution is not preserved in mixture models. It is really just a labelling issue. If you switch your two Gaussian distributions, you will end up with the same likelihood.

The reason you will see the estimated means get switched in your 3rd and 5th datasets is most likely related to how your optimizer works. Technically, no optimizer will guarantee to converge to the global optimum in general unless your objective function is convex/concave. This is unfortunately not the case for mixture model likelihood. Your program is probably using some local optimizer for parameter estimation and restart several times to look for better solutions. Therefore, your final estimate will depend on the initial values, where your optimizer starts. For example for dataset 1, if your optimizer starts at (15,30) you will likely to get the order you want. What if it starts at (35,10)?

My final observation is that your results (first table) don't seem to match your description. If you fix the second mean, you should see exactly 25 for mean2. It looks like you are still using some procedure to fit the standard mixture model rather than explicit writing down and optimizing the likelihood for the constrained mixture.

Peter